# In React Development - VS Code: “go to definition” not working on exported class

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I can't use "go to definition" feature in VS Code on exported class clicking on method,  it just says "no definition found"

After googling found that the imported class must have typescript definition files to this feature to work. 
How to create these definition files and how to include in react app, I am using web pack (create-react-app tool).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can do.

If the imported component is a library you can try and install @types/library or check whether the types are available for that library

If it was created by you or if you have the source-code of the class you can set `declaration: true` in `tsconfig.json`. It will automatically generate the .d.ts file

Or you can create a .d.ts file. Its actually not that complicated. For more details on this check out https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and in my case, it worked doing the following.

Try creating a `jsconfig.json` at the **root** of the workspace with the content:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

This tells our JS language features to also handle JSX files in a project.

Comment: For me this only worked once I also added `"baseUrl": "."` to the `compilerOptions` object.